# Processing time ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

In Ajax is possible to calculate the processing time of the request? For example, if the extraction of data takes less than 3 seconds, to display a message and to enroll in logs by ajax. If possible you show me an example.
P.S. Sorry for my bad english

Comment: Yes! start a timer just before your request, compare it to the current time after the request finishes!

Comment: you can record the before and after time of the ajax call

Comment: @Dale, if more 3 seconds, is possible to write in logs this event?

Answer (score 1):

To get response time you can try something like this but as per this example you have to use jQuery.

```
var starttime = new Date().getTime();

jQuery.get('your-url-goes-here', data, 
    function(data, status, xhr) {
        var requesttime = new Date().getTime() - starttime;
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use timers :

```
function ajaxFunction() {
    var startTime = new Date().getTime();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "url.php",
        data: {},
        success: function(ret) {
            // script is done
            var endTime = new Date().getTime();
            var totalTime = endTime - startTime; // this is in milliseconds

            if (totalTime >= 3000) {
                console.log("Script took " + totalTime + " ms" );
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Note that `getTime()` returns milliseconds. So you'll have to check for 3000ms = 3s

Comment: if more 3 seconds, is possible to write in logs this event with another ajax request?

Comment: @Ion if it took more than 3 seconds (aka `totalTime >= 3000`), my code already log something in the console. Instead of logging in the console, you can do whatever you want - like call another function.